# Is it possible to make html table column text cropped with three dots by CSS only when there is overflow in the table?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I have a basic HTML table with 4 columns and 4 rows.Basically width:0 given to first three columns to make them as wide as length of the text inside the column and the last one is free to fill the available space like below (Sorry for bad drawing)

[image]

When text gets longer and page resized like below , overflow occurs and scrolling appears on x-axis.

[image]

What I want in this case is cropping the text with three dots when there's overflow(in another saying when there is no enough space for the last column to fill the space).So no need to scroll in x-axis.See the image below to get my expectation.

[image]

You can see that there's no overflow occured and text is cropped with three dots.For demonstration of my expectation, I just set max-width:549px as a default but somehow I should make this dynamically and make it work as expected for all screen width sizes.Is it possible to do with CSS?

Here you can find the code snippet

```css
.table-responsive {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
.table-thin table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.table-thin table tbody tr td {
    padding-top: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 30px;
}
.table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0 1px;
}
.table-thin table td, .table-thin table th {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    border:1px solid;
    white-space: pre;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.table-thin table td:not(:last-child), .table-thin table th:not(:last-child) {
    width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive table-thin">
    <table class="table table--h30">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th><strong>September</strong></th>
                <th><strong>October</strong></th>
                <th><strong>November</strong></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>First row</strong></td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Second row</strong></td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Third row</strong></td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Fourth row</strong></td>
                <td>104</td>
                <td>102</td>
                <td>103</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: mabye wrapping it and setting a fixed wrapper width would be a solution?

Comment: @Dev could you come up with working code sample ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `max-width: 0;` and a `colgroup`

```css
.table-responsive {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
.table-thin table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.table-thin table tbody tr td {
    padding-top: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 30px;
}
.table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0 1px;
}
.table-thin td, .table-thin th {
   border: 1px solid;
   white-space: nowrap;
   width: 0;
}

.table-thin td:first-child {
   max-width: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   white-space: nowrap;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;  
}
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive table-thin">
    <table class="table table--h30">
         <colgroup>
           <col span="1">
           <col span="3" style="width:1%">
         </colgroup>
    
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th><strong>September</strong></th>
                <th><strong>October</strong></th>
                <th><strong>November</strong></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>First row asdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd</strong></td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Second row</strong></td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Third row</strong></td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Fourth row</strong></td>
                <td>104</td>
                <td>102</td>
                <td>103</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but this is not what I mean you see that still there is scrolling bar when width gets smaller after some point.Also I meant cropping text actually for the first column not the last one

Comment: @TimuçinÇiçek in your first image the last column is wide, but ok. I also do not see a scrolling bar so i don't understand what you mean with that.

Comment: @TimuçinÇiçek first column is now the wide one...

Comment: but last column is not that wide and flex as I described

Comment: @TimuçinÇiçek "See the image below to get my expectation." My answer looks just like what you expected. What do you want?

Comment: I'll add a video about it seems like image is not enough

Comment: @TimuçinÇiçek You don't need a video you need to answer my questions, so i can help you.